# Fratini subgroup is the smallest normal subgroup which quotientize a p group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Prove that if $P$ be the p-group then   $\phi(P)$ is the smallest normal subgroup for which $P $\ $\phi(P)$ is elementary abelian group. Where $\phi(P)$ is a frattini subgroup of $P$ . I am trying to solve this.  But really can't do that. So any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Hint: every maximal subgroup of a finite $p$-group $P$ is normal and has index $p$ in $P$.

Comment: Sorry I noticed that and really couldn't solve it from there

Comment: Can u give me another hint

Comment: You are presumably supposed to solve this yourself! The previous hint implies that $P/\Phi(P)$ is elementary abelian.

Comment: I know it implies elementary abelian and solved it. I can't solve why this is the smallest subgroup for which the quotient is elementary abelian

Comment: Assume that $P/N$ is elementary abelian and prove that $\Phi(P) \le N$.